# How to handle a sample when the size differs?

Tags: regression, sample-size

I am a bit puzzled.

Assume an international forum where governments, NGOs and companies vote either in favor or against a particular agreement/treaty. I want to analyze the determinants of the voting behavior of each actor.

What is puzzling in this case is that the number of governments, NGOs and companies is not the same (although NGOs and companies officially represent countries but are independent from how their governments vote). So for example, for the year 2000, 50 governments were selected to this forum, 45 NGOs and 25 companies.

One way of analyzing their voting behavior is to generate a sample for each actor and analyze it separately. Are there any other ways to analyze this? I am going to use their voting behavior as my dependent variable, so combining them into one (government + NGO or government + company) does not work as their number differ.

Comment: Since you're dealing with a 1/0 (in favor or not) outcome, and some covariates (e.g. x,y,z) that are clustered within governments, NGO's or companies, I recommend either running separate models for governments, NGO's or companies. Or, you can try a linear mixed effects model to control for cluster size.